# Need help with correct SQL

Tags: mysql

So I'm a noobie, starter, beginner - throw all of the above at me.  I'm trying to create a query that will search through a database and return blah blah blah.  The problem is, it isn't quite working.  Here's an example query -  As you can see, above other things, I am trying to return results from someone with the last name Johnson

```
SELECT BookingInfo.ClinicID, BookingInfo.BookingDate, BookingInfo.BookingTime, 
  BookingInfo.Status, PatientBooking.FirstName, PatientBooking.LastName, 
  PatientBooking.DateOfBirth 
FROM BookingInfo LEFT JOIN PatientBooking 
  ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID 
WHERE PatientBooking.LastName = 'Johnson' AND BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' 
  OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2' 
ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

This returns results with Johnson, but others as well.  Another:

```
SELECT BookingInfo.ClinicID, BookingInfo.BookingDate, BookingInfo.BookingTime, 
  BookingInfo.Status, PatientBooking.FirstName, PatientBooking.LastName, 
  PatientBooking.DateOfBirth 
FROM BookingInfo LEFT JOIN PatientBooking 
  ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID 
WHERE BookingInfo.BookingDate = '05-18-2010' AND BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' 
  OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2' 
ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

This returns results from the date I specified, but others as well.  Am I doing something wrong with my syntax?  Have I no clue what I'm doing?  Please help a beginner out. Thanks!

Comment: The AND and OR are getting confused. Put the two OR conditions in a set of brackets and try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit should go to @Randolph Potter:

```
SELECT BookingInfo.ClinicID, BookingInfo.BookingDate, BookingInfo.BookingTime, BookingInfo.Status, PatientBooking.FirstName, PatientBooking.LastName, PatientBooking.DateOfBirth 
FROM BookingInfo 
    LEFT JOIN PatientBooking ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID 
WHERE 
    BookingInfo.BookingDate = '05-18-2010' AND 
    ( BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2' ) 
ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

Comment: Randolph -- if you care to replicate this answer I will delete mine.

Comment: Keep the points. I didn't have the patience to write it all out :-)

Answer (score 5):

Review the order of precedence between AND and OR.

In arithmetic, multiplication has higher precedence than addition.

Example: 10+10*10 = 110, but (10+10)*10 = 200.

It's similar with AND and OR.  AND has higher precedence than OR, so this without parentheses:

```
WHERE BookingInfo.BookingDate = '05-18-2010' AND BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' 
  OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2'
```

works like this:

```
WHERE (BookingInfo.BookingDate = '05-18-2010' AND BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1') 
  OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2'
```

But you want it to work like this:

```
WHERE BookingInfo.BookingDate = '05-18-2010' AND 
  (BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2')
```

So put in the parentheses to make sure the order of precedence works how you want it to.

---

I also just noticed you are using dates in MM-DD-YYYY format, which is not recognized by MySQL for date literals.  You must use YYYY-MM-DD format.  That could be causing a different problem.

```
SELECT DATE('05-18-2010'); -- returns NULL
SELECT DATE('2010-05-18'); -- returns 2010-05-18
```

---

Re your comment:

> Are you sure that AND has a higher precedence?

Yes, I'm sure AND has higher precedence than OR.  For one thing, the hierarchy of precedence of all operators in MySQL is documented here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html

Let's go through an example using your originally stated problem:

```
BookingDate   ClinicID 
2010-05-18    2
2008-05-18    2

WHERE BookingInfo.BookingDate = '2010-05-18' AND 
  BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2'
```

Using this expression, only the first row should match.  But you found that both rows match, even though the date of the second row is not right.  Why?  Let's replace each comparison with either TRUE or FALSE:

```
TRUE AND FALSE OR TRUE
FALSE AND FALSE OR TRUE
```

If OR had higher precedence, it would evaluate like this:

```
TRUE AND (FALSE OR TRUE)
FALSE AND (FALSE OR TRUE)
```

Since any value combined with OR TRUE yields TRUE, the subexpression inside these parentheses would reduce to:

```
TRUE AND (TRUE)
FALSE AND (TRUE)
```

And the second row would not match, because FALSE AND TRUE yields FALSE.  But that can't be, since you found the second row incorrectly matches.

In fact, AND has higher precedence than OR, so it really evaluates as if you had parentheses around the AND subexpression:

```
(TRUE AND FALSE) OR TRUE
(FALSE AND FALSE) OR TRUE
```

Which reduces to:

```
(FALSE) OR TRUE
(FALSE) OR TRUE
```

In both cases, FALSE OR TRUE yields TRUE, and both rows match.

So without parentheses, the default semantics are that AND has higher precedence than OR.  You need the parentheses:

```
WHERE BookingInfo.BookingDate = '2010-05-18' AND 
  (BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2')
```

Comment: Are you sure that `AND` has a higher precedence? I tested it on this page http://sqlzoo.net/3b.htm and it seems to me that the statements are executed from left to right with equal precedence given (excluding parenthesis, of course).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you don't have parenthesis around your OR condition.  Try the updated version below:

```
SELECT BookingInfo.ClinicID, 
       BookingInfo.BookingDate, 
       BookingInfo.BookingTime,
       BookingInfo.Status, 
       PatientBooking.FirstName, 
       PatientBooking.LastName, 
       PatientBooking.DateOfBirth 
FROM       BookingInfo 
LEFT JOIN  PatientBooking 
ON         BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID 
WHERE      PatientBooking.LastName = 'Johnson' 
AND        BookingInfo.ClinicID IN ('1', '2') 
ORDER BY   BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

Also, adding a little formatting to your SQL will make it much more readable.  This will help you get answers on SO as well as help anyone else who ends up looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parentheses around the part of the `WHERE` clause that comes before the `OR`. In the first example, what you *mean* is

```
SELECT
    BookingInfo.ClinicID,
    BookingInfo.BookingDate,
    BookingInfo.BookingTime,
    BookingInfo.Status,
    PatientBooking.FirstName,
    PatientBooking.LastName,
    PatientBooking.DateOfBirth
FROM
    BookingInfo
    LEFT JOIN PatientBooking ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID
WHERE
    PatientBooking.LastName = 'Johnson' AND
    ( BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR
      BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2'
      )
ORDER BY
    BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

but because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, what you are *actually doing* is

```
SELECT
    BookingInfo.ClinicID,
    BookingInfo.BookingDate,
    BookingInfo.BookingTime,
    BookingInfo.Status,
    PatientBooking.FirstName,
    PatientBooking.LastName,
    PatientBooking.DateOfBirth
FROM
    BookingInfo
    LEFT JOIN PatientBooking ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID
WHERE
    ( PatientBooking.LastName = 'Johnson' AND
      BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1'
      ) OR
    BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2'
ORDER BY
    BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

Thus, you are going to see *every* row in which `ClinicID` is equal to 2; not just Johnson's.

Answer (score 0):

If you put brackets around the 2 ClinicID conditions, it should work.

See below:

```
SELECT BookingInfo.ClinicID, BookingInfo.BookingDate, BookingInfo.BookingTime, BookingInfo.Status, PatientBooking.FirstName, PatientBooking.LastName, PatientBooking.DateOfBirth FROM BookingInfo LEFT JOIN PatientBooking ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID WHERE PatientBooking.LastName = 'Johnson' AND (BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2') ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC 

SELECT BookingInfo.ClinicID, BookingInfo.BookingDate, BookingInfo.BookingTime, BookingInfo.Status, PatientBooking.FirstName, PatientBooking.LastName, PatientBooking.DateOfBirth FROM BookingInfo LEFT JOIN PatientBooking ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID WHERE BookingInfo.BookingDate = '05-18-2010' AND (BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2') ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```