# Easy SQL Syntax NOT LIKE with AND operators seem to be ignored

Tags: sql, operators, sql-like, not-operator

Thank you so much for helping! Nothing I seem to do works here. What I want to do is remove rows with a certain value in a certain column. Like so:

```
Where SegStart_Date between getdate()-90 and getdate()-1
    And q.Center not like 'Collections Center'
    And q.Center not like 'Cable Store'
    And q.Center not like 'Business Services Center'
    And q.Center not like 'Escalations'
```

Yet all my attempts to NOT are futile as the query returns rows with them anyway. What did I do wrong here?

The whole query is provided below:

```
Select segstart,
CASE
--when hour is = 0 and min < 30 then 0
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 0 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('0' as int)
--when hour is = 0 and min > 30 then 30
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 0 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('30' as int)
--when hour is 1 and min < 30 then 100
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 1 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('100' as int)
--when hour is 1 and min > 30 then 130
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 1 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('130' as int)
--when hour is 2 and min < 30 then 200
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 2 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('200' as int)
--when hour is 2 and min > 30 then 230
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 2 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('230' as int)
--when hour is 3 and min < 30 then 300
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 3 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('300' as int)
--when hour is 3 and min > 30 then 330
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 3 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('330' as int)
--when hour is 4 and min < 30 then 400
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 4 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('400' as int)
--when hour is 4 and min > 30 then 430
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 4 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('430' as int)
--when hour is 5 and min < 30 then 500
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 5 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('500' as int)
--when hour is 5 and min > 30 then 530
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 5 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('530' as int)
--when hour is 6 and min < 30 then 600
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 6 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('600' as int)
--when hour is 6 and min > 30 then 630
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 6 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('630' as int)
--when hour is 7 and min < 30 then 700
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 7 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('700' as int)
--when hour is 7 and min > 30 then 730
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 7 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('730' as int)
--when hour is 8 and min < 30 then 800
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 8 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('800' as int)
--when hour is 8 and min > 30 then 830
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 8 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('830' as int)
--when hour is 9 and min < 30 then 900
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 9 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('900' as int)
--when hour is 9 and min > 30 then 930
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 9 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('930' as int)
--when hour is 10 and min < 30 then 1000
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 10 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1000' as int)
--when hour is 10 and min > 30 then 1030
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 10 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1030' as int)
--when hour is 11 and min < 30 then 1100
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 11 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1100' as int)
--when hour is 11 and min > 30 then 1130
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 11 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1130' as int)
--when hour is 12 and min < 30 then 1200
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 12 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30  THEN CAST('1200' as int)
--when hour is 12 and min < 30 then 1230
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 12 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1230' as int)
--when hour is 13 and min < 30 then 1300
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 13 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1300' as int)
--when hour is 13 and min > 30 then 1330
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 13 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1330' as int)
--when hour is 14 and min < 30 then 1400
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 14 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1400' as int)
--when hour is 14 and min > 30 then 1430
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 14 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1430' as int)
--when hour is 15 and min < 30 then 1500
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 15 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1500' as int)
--when hour is 15 and min > 30 then 1530
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 15 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1530' as int)
--when hour is 16 and min < 30 then 1600
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 16 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1600' as int)
--when hour is 16 and min > 30 then 1630
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 16 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1630' as int)
--when hour is 17 and min < 30 then 1700
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 17 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1700' as int)
--when hour is 17 and min > 30 then 1730
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 17 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1730' as int)
--when hour is 18 and min < 30 then 1800
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 18 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1800' as int)
--when hour is 18 and min > 30 then 1830
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 18 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1830' as int)
--when hour is 19 and min < 30 then 1900
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 19 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('1900' as int)
--when hour is 19 and min > 30 then 1930
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 19 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('1930' as int)
--when hour is 20 and min < 30 then 2000
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 20 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('2000' as int)
--when hour is 20 and min > 30 then 2030
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 20 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('2030' as int)
--when hour is 21 and min < 30 then 2100
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 21 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('2100' as int)
--when hour is 21 and min > 30 then 2130
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 21 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('2130' as int)
--when hour is 22 and min < 30 then 2200
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 22 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('2200' as int)
--when hour is 22 and min > 30 then 2230
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 22 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('2230' as int)
--when hour is 23 and min < 30 then 2300
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 23 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('2300' as int)
--when hour is 23 and min > 30 then 2330
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 23 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) >= 30 THEN CAST('2330' as int)
ELSE Null End as Interval,
    FiscalMonthYear,
    SegStart_Date,
    dialed_num,
    callid,
    Name,
    t.Queue AS 'Xferto',
    TransferType,
    RepLName+', '+RepFName AS Agent,
    SupLName+', '+SupFName AS Sup,
    MgrLName+', '+MgrFName AS Manager,
    q.Center,
    q.Queue AS 'Xferfrom',
    e.anslogin,
    e.origlogin,
    t.Extension,
    transferred,
    disposition,
    talktime,
    dispsplit
From CMS_ECH.dbo.CaliforniaECH e

INNER JOIN Cal_RemReporting.dbo.TransferVDNs t on e.dialed_num = t.Extension
INNER JOIN InfoQuest.dbo.IQ_Employee_Profiles_v3_AvayaId q on e.origlogin = q.AvayaID
INNER JOIN Cal_RemReporting.dbo.udFiscalMonthTable f on e.SegStart_Date = f.Tdate

Where SegStart_Date between getdate()-90 and getdate()-1
    And q.Center not like 'Collections Center'
    And q.Center not like 'Cable Store'
    And q.Center not like 'Business Services Center'
    And q.Center not like 'Escalations'
    And SegStart_Date between RepToSup_StartDate and RepToSup_EndDate
    And SegStart_Date between SupToMgr_StartDate and SupToMgr_EndDate
    And SegStart_Date between Avaya_StartDate and Avaya_EndDate
    And SegStart_Date between RepQueue_StartDate and RepQueue_EndDate
    AND e.transferred like '1'
    OR e.disposition like '4' order by center
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a table scan. Do you have an index that would make that query efficient? If there are few enough rows, you could probably make this into a subselect to avoid the table scan.

Comment: Replace that humongous CASE expression with `100*DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN 0 ELSE 30 END`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused about the precedence between AND and OR.

OR has lower precedence than AND, which makes your query return any row where `e.disposition like '4'`

I wrote a lengthy explanation for an equivalent problem in my answer to [Need help with correct SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154102/need-help-with-correct-sql/3154138#3154138) a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `OR` right at the bottom, which I presume will suck in some rows even if they have the excluded values. The effect, without parentheses, is `(A AND B AND C ... AND Z) OR W`. Perhaps you need to group your predicates differently.

While we're at it, you don't need `LIKE` here, since you are looking for exact matches. Do this instead:

```
Where SegStart_Date between getdate()-90 and getdate()-1
    And q.Center not in ('Collections Center',
                         'Cable Store',
                         'Business Services Center',
                         'Escalations')
```

The same goes for the stuff towards the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bracketing problem:

```
   AND e.transferred like '1'
    OR e.disposition like '4'
```

Is that supposed to be

```
   AND (e.transferred like '1'
    OR e.disposition like '4')
```

or

```
   (... 
   AND e.transferred like '1')
    OR e.disposition like '4'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the precedence for boolean operators in SQL is the following order.

- Not
- And
- Or

which explains the problem you were seeing.

Another thing I noticed in the code you posted is that it contains lines like

```
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 0 
      AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN CAST('0' as int)
```

This could/should be written without the cast from string to int as

```
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) = 0 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart) < 30 THEN 0
```

But in fact I think you could get rid of that whole huge case expression and replace it with

```
100*DATEPART(HOUR, segstart) +30*(DATEPART(MINUTE, segstart)/30)  as Interval
```

Comment: Martin Smith, you sir are a life saver! That was amazing! Thank you! Spot on! +1!